# Create carousel cards as in fb messenger in react js

Tags: reactjs, chat, carousel

Am developing a chat widget like intercom widget in react js and I want to add carousel cards component, as in facebook messenger.

[image]

On mobile, when user swipe one card, the next one should come and center itself, and on the web, there should be a left and right button, which when clicked show respective card.

I searched and couldn't find any packages for this. 
How can I implement this? Am new to react.

Comment: Are you still looking for the answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the other answers, You have the carousel component in react-bootstrap and reactstrap.

Personally, I feel reactstrap have better documentation than react-bootstrap. You can simply found an example for carousel in their official doc.
https://reactstrap.github.io/components/carousel/

But, Those example doesn't have the swipe event as you expected and I am also can't find any carousel with swipe event for both web and mobile view. So finally, I have decided to make a custom carousel with the swipe event.

For the web, I have used `onDragStart` and `onDragEnd`. And For the mobile view, I used `onTouchStart`, `onTouchMove` and `onTouchEnd` to detect the swipe left and right.

Here the changes.

```
//Global variables to hold the last and current X-axis positions.
var lastX = 0;
var currentX = 0;

//For web, detect swipe left and right based on mouse drag events. 
handleMouse = e => {
    e.persist();
    let type = e.type.toLowerCase();
    if (type === "dragstart") {
      lastX = e.clientX;
    } else {
      if (lastX === 0 || e.clientX === 0 || lastX === e.clientX) {
        return;
      }
      if (e.clientX > lastX) {
        this.previous();
        console.log("swife right");
      } else {
        this.next();
        console.log("swife left");
      }
    }
  };

  //For mobile, detect swipe left and right based on touch events. 
  handleTouch = e => {
    e.persist();
    let type = e.type.toLowerCase();

    if (type === "touchstart") {
      lastX = e.touches[0].clientX;
    }

    if (type === "touchmove") {
      currentX = e.touches[0].clientX;
    }

    if (type === "touchend") {
      if (lastX === 0 || currentX === 0 || lastX === currentX) {
        return;
      }
      if (currentX > lastX) {
        this.previous();
        console.log("swife right");
      } else {
        this.next();
        console.log("swife left");
      }
    }
  };

  //Modified render.
  render() {
    const { activeIndex } = this.state;
    const slides = items.map(item => {
      return (
        <CarouselItem
          onExiting={this.onExiting}
          onExited={this.onExited}
          key={item.src}
        >
          <img
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
            src={item.src}
            alt={item.altText}
            onTouchStart={e => this.handleTouch(e)}
            onTouchMove={e => this.handleTouch(e)}
            onTouchEnd={e => this.handleTouch(e)}
            onDragStart={e => this.handleMouse(e)}
            onDragEnd={e => this.handleMouse(e)}
          />
        </CarouselItem>
      );
    });

    return (
      <Carousel
        activeIndex={activeIndex}
        next={this.next}
        previous={this.previous}
        interval={false}
      >
        {slides}

        <CarouselControl
          direction="prev"
          directionText="Previous"
          onClickHandler={this.previous}
        />
        <CarouselControl
          direction="next"
          directionText="Next"
          onClickHandler={this.next}
        />
      </Carousel>
    );
   }
  }
```

Working [demo](https://8131rv6v50.codesandbox.io/) and the [fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/8131rv6v50).

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in another answer you can find a component that has already been built and use that.

However you can implement it yourself using [CSS scroll snap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap) and flexbox.

Here's an article which outlines this approach (not in react but still applies).

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/css-scroll-snap

Answer (score 0):

react-bootstrap has a carousel component

[here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/carousel/)
and there is react-responsive-carousel
[here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-carousel)